# Match and Param object in Next.js router for Server side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js, high-order-component

I am trying to convert my client side application to server side rendered because of problem in SEO. For client side I have used react router which is passing the prop to other child components while render.

**Below is current code**

**App.js**

```
render() {
return (
<Switch>
<Route path={constant.pathId + constant.pathGender} render={(props) => <HomeScreen {...props} />} />
</Switch>
);
}
```

**Const**

```
export const industryRegexGender = "(men||women)";
export const industryRegex = "(en-kw||en-qa||en-ae||en-bh||en-om||en-sa||ar-kw||ar-qa||ar-ae||ar-bh||ar-om||ar-sa)";
export const pathId = `/:id${industryRegex}`;
export const pathGender = `/:gender${industryRegexGender}`;
```

**Homescreen component** ( Getting the value here in the child components)

```
let paramId = this.props.match.params.id
```

**Screenshot of console**

[image]

**I am not sure how to achieve this with Next/router, already tried following next.js documentation.**

**Any help of sample would be really appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

if your component is functional component then use "useRouter" hook.

```
  import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

  const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  //console.log(router) to see router object
  const { pid } = router.query
  return <p>Post: {pid}</p>}

  export default Post
```

if your function is class component, you use withRouter()

```
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'

function Page({ router }) {
  return <p>{router.pathname}</p>
}

export default withRouter(Page)
```